# Functions that return const char*

Tags: c++, pointers, char

Although the following code does work, I do not know why. Please explain me.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const char *f()
{
    const char *p = "Hello!\n";

    return p;
}

int main()
{
    cout << f() << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

From what I learnt, the 7 chars in f() are allocated on the stack (?), meaning that their memory will be released as soon as f() ends, however, the pointer returned by f() still points to a valid address in the application memory (meaning "Hello!" is successfully sent to the output). Why?

Same thing goes for

```
const int *f()
{
    int i = 5;
    const int *p = &i;

    return p;
}

int main()
{
    cout << *f() << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

What you´ve learned is correct, it´s *not* allowed to use local function variables
(ie. their used memory) anymore after the function ends.
If it works currently it´s nothing more than coincidence:
No other code has used this piece of memory in the meantime
for own things, so the old value is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Your second code snippet causes undefined behaviour. The reason why it **seems** to work is, that you are lucky and the memory has not been overwritten.

However (as in the comment below mentioned) the first snippet is valid.

Comment: Only the second snippet invokes UB, the first one is just fine.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious the first snippet also suffers from the fact that the memory of the string might be released, right?

Comment: @Ben No. Look again.